# 3x3 grid in Python from list

Tags: python

I have a list generated from a text file and need to put it into a 3x3 grid. I have tried multiple ways but they all seem to be for older versions of Python.

```
with open("words.txt") as f: #open/import words from words.txt
words = [x.strip() for x in f] #add to list
```

Is what I have to add words from the text file to a list. There are 10 words in the file, 9 are shown. I already have the 'remove/add a word from the list by getting it out of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want the last nine or first nine, if you want the first nine remove the first next(f), I presume each word is on a separate line:

```
with open("words.txt") as f: #open/import words from words.txt
    next(f) # skip first?
    words  = [[next(f).strip() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Or use itertools.islice:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("words.txt") as f: #open/import words from words.txt
    next(f)
    words = [list(map(str.rstrip,islice(f,None,3))) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Does this change the list in anyway. I need to use the list twice after for a 3x3 grid and also compare the word that was removed with an input and the word that was added with a user input?

Comment: You cannot iterate over a file object more than once. If you want use `f.seek(0)` to move pointer back to the start of the file and iterate over f to get each line again. As far as changing the list I am not sure what you mean. The code I provided creates a 3 * 3 list

Answer (score 0):

Just to be a little different, I am assuming that all words are contained on one line.  That way I can read the line with readline(), split, and slice away the first element.  If I wanted the first 9, I could say [:9], or obviously other slices from lines with more text.

```
import numpy as np

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fp:
    words = fp.readline().split()[1:]

threebythree = np.array(words).reshape((3,3))
```

But what I wanted to show was what you are doing is actually reshaping a matrix and that can be done with a toolkit such as numpy.  First you read the list into an array (a 9-dimensional 1D-array), and then reshape it into 3,3 with the above command.  The list "words" in this example is kept intact for further processing if desired.